# ASP.NET MVC5 HttpPostedFileBase always returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-blob-storage

I have looked up many similar questions but to no avail. Solutions range from ensuring the *name* of the input field is same as the param, and including *multipart/form-data.* When POSTing, the image is always returning null.

***Confirm.cshtml***

```
@model IQueryable<SGHealthDesktop.Models.Patient>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Confirm", "Doctor", new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", guid = Model.First().PatientId }, FormMethod.Post, null)) {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @if (Model != null) {

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.First().PatientName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.First().PatientName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" } })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.First().UniqueId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.First().UniqueId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" } })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.First().Evidence, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.First().Evidence, new { type = "file", name = "uploadFile", id = "uploadFile", required = "required", @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Request" class="btn btn-success" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                }
```

***DoctorController.cs***

```
// POST: Doctor/Confirm
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Confirm")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Confirmed(string guid, HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile) {
            try {
                if (ModelState.IsValid) { // to be binded later. 
                    ImageService imageService = new ImageService();
                    var imageUrl = imageService.UploadImage(UploadedFile);

                    var currentTime = DateTime.Now;

                    db.Appeal.Add(new Appeal {
                        DoctorId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                        PatientId = guid,
                        Evidence = imageUrl,
                        Time = currentTime, 
                        IsApprove = false
                    });
                    TempData["Message"] = "Appeal is being processed. Check the Request page for outcome.";
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                } else {
                    var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
                }
            } catch (DataException dex) {
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Patient");
        }
```

May I know where did I go wrong?

**Update**

```
// GET: Doctor/Confirm
        public ActionResult Confirm(string id) {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) {
                return View("Error");
            }

            IQueryable<Patient> nameQuery = (from user in db.Users
                                             where user.Id.Equals(id)
                                             select new Patient {
                                                 PatientId = user.Id,
                                                 PatientName = user.FullName,
                                                 UniqueId = user.UniqueId
                                             });
            if (nameQuery == null) {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(nameQuery);
        }
```

Comment: 2 issues - the 1st as per the dupe and the 2nd is that you do not have a file input with `name="uploadFile"` (using `new { name = "uploadFile" }` does absolutely nothing fortunately)

Comment: Are you sure that @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.First().Evidence, new { type = "file", ... }) renders as input type='file' ?

Comment: And what is the point of generating inputs that are disabled and that you do not want to post back and labels associated with controls that cannot be focussed? - just use `<div>@DisplayFor(m => m.First().PatientName)</div>` and style the div to look like a control is you want.

Comment: @doker Yes it does. @ Stephen Muecke Thanks! Made the necessary changes and it's working now.

Comment: Not really - Your code is not making sense. Every form is identical and will post back the same value for `string guid` (the value of the first`PatientId`) and you generating a lot of invalid html.

Comment: Is it possible for you to pinpoint for me examples of invalid html which I have generated?

Comment: You model is a collection so I assume yo have just omitted the loop from the code in your question - otherwise what would be the point of passing a collection to the view?

Comment: Oh I wasn't intending for it to be a collection. I'm just trying to pass 1 object of Patient. I retrieved that object using LINQ and somehow if I omit IQueryable, it won't work. Please see my updated question containing the retrieval of the object. I already felt that it was a wrong way of doing it, but I'm not quite sure of what are the other ways.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113628/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kai).